# Error when trying to use a PieChart (hellocharts) on an Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to use the external library "hellocharts" in my project. I have linked the library to my project already, but when the activity that has the chart starts, the whole app crash with the exception: "Error inflating class lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.PieChartView".

I don't know what the problem can be. The java class (when I use the Charts) don't seem to have that problem (it doesn't get compile errors of not finding the library).

Here it is the .xml file of the activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Dia"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Dia" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Semana"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Semana" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Mes"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Mes" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Temporizador"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Temp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Estadisticas"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Stats" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Tienda"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Tienda" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.PieChartView
            android:id="@+id/graphic_pie_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.826" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_asignatura"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/graphic_pie_chart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/graphic_pie_chart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_tiempo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/graphic_pie_chart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_asignatura"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_asignatura"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_asignatura"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

And here it is the gradle files

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.ucm"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()// Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Could you copy all the stacktrace of you crash?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with some similar library. Later found that
just implementing library is not enough. You sometimes have to add few addon lines to our project settings files as per requirement. (e.g. `gradle.properties`, `settings.gradle`,... etc).

Following helped me :)

**android.enableJetifier=true** to *gradle.properties* file

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already discussed in the same github library page. Seems like they haven't found a solution yet.

[Issue Discussion Page](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/issues/86)

However, you can use other libraries to get pie chart.

Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/PM1509/Chart-App)

Referred from this [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-pie-chart-graph-in-android)